# Why ArcMap 10.2 crashes when running model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I`m running a simple model in ArcMap 10.2, which makes my ArcMap crashing (closing and then an error message pops in saying that ArcMap has encountered a serious error, and there is an option to report it to ESRI). Basically I want to rasterise some polygons, so I built a model: Iterate Feature Class> Project> Polygon To Raster. Does anyone have an idea why my ArcMap crashes when I run this particular model? (I do run a lot of different model, but have never encountered this issue before...)

Comment: "Crashes" can be used to describe a number of symptoms so can you edit your question to describe precisely how it crashes, please?

Comment: have you checked the resolution of your input raster ? Why do you need to iterate ?

Comment: The input is a features class that is the reason why I need to iterate it. The output will be raster

Comment: Might help if you have a screenshot of the model. Have you checked that the model runs for just one polygon before testing it on multiple ones? Have you considered running Polygon To Raster as a batch instead of building a model (if so, did that work)?

Comment: I would recommend running the processes manually (outside of the model) one by one to see if you can isolate the error.

Comment: What system are you running 10.2 on?  I have a that build running on Windows Server 2012 that crashes in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a few things to find the root cause.
First, can you isolate the issue down to particular feature classes? This might indicate that there may be an problem with your feature class. 
Second, try running the model in ArcCatalog and test. 
Third, try disabling any third party extensions you might have installed.

Comment: ++ I've had a lot of luck with running individual tools in Catalog that weren't working in ArcMap that for whatever reason will work when run in catalog. Another thing I've done is make a copy of the mxd I'm working with and run it in that. Or even just a new blank map document will sometimes work, too.

Answer (score 1):

So after considering several options (including replacing the `Polygon To Raster` with the `Feature To Raster` - which did not produce the expected result) I decided to trim the name of the feature class. And the miracle happened, ArcMap did not crash. Looks like that Arc Model Builder is happy with short names but will crash if the input has a lengthy name. The output files can very easily be renamed any time with the Orscar`s Renamer.